# Floating label background color over edge

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a floating label which hovers on the top border of an input, and removes (overlays?) the part of the border that it sits on.

The following works well if the inside of the input has the same background color as the outside (using Tailwind):

```
<div className='inline-flex relative align-top'>
  <input id={id} type='text' className={inputClassname} />
  <label id={`{$id}-label`} htmlFor={id} className={labelClassname}>
    Label here
  </label>
</div>
```

with `labelClassname` like (slightly shortened with sizes, formatted here to make easier to line up, `peer-placeholder-shown` shortened to `peer-plc-s`) - problem here presumably comes from `bg-white`...

```
absolute block z-[1] transition-all bg-white px-1 
text-gray-700                       -top-2            left-2 
peer-focus:text-gray-700 peer-focus:-top-2 peer-focus:left-2 
peer-plc-s:text-gray-500 peer-plc-s:top-4  peer-plc-s:left-4
```

and `inputClassname` like:

```
peer placeholder-transparent border px-4 pt-3 pb-1
focus-visible:outline-none text-lg 
border-gray-400 box-border
border-b-4 focus:border-b-secondaryc
```

Input with no interaction, label in box (fine)
[image: Empty input with label in place]
Input with text and focus (fine)
[image: Input with label raised and focus]
Input with a different background (here caused by `disabled`) - the background is set here to `bg-white`, so now the box is visible.
[image: Problematic disabled input with visible label box]

Setting `bg-inherit` or `bg-transparent` doesn't hide the line:
[image: bg-inherit versions]

How can I make a label that occludes the top border, but doesn't have a background which looks odd when the two sides of the border are not the same color?

Comment: _"Setting bg-inherit or bg-transparent doesn't hide the line"_ - well that a _transparent_ background won't hide anything, should be obvious as can be ... And inherit would inherit from the ancestor elements, not from the input which is a sibling of the label.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob - thanks, I'm using T(J)SX, so omitting the closing slash gives me a syntax error, but good to know for pure HTML (and since the question didn't mention React, worth knowing).

Comment: @CBroe - is there a suitable combination of pseudo-specifiers that can get me the peer color? If so, it still doesn't fix the problem of two colors and an overlap (which perhaps requires a pair of divs with no borders and different colors?) but could allow me to position it with curved border and join it to the top left corner or similar.

Alternatively, can the pseudo elements `before` or `after` be used to create the pair of divs? Which colors should I use to identify the colors of the input inside and the outside color (maybe outside is `bg-inherit`?).

Comment: If you only need this in "static" form, you might be able to use pseudo elements on the label element itself, to replace the actual upper border of the input field. But if you want to add a transition for that "move" from inside the input, to inside the border, then it's probably going to get real tricky.